# IOS equivalent of android appear on top

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

Is there an IOS equivalent of androids appear on top permission? An example is the alarmy app where when the alarm goes off the screen with whatever task you have to turn it off shows up when the alarm rings.

I am struggling to find the permission for this or if it even exists. I am not entirely sure what i want.

Comment: LiveActivity sounds like the closest thing.

Comment: There is no direct equivalent. There are alternatives like notifications, live activities and Home Screen widgets